# When I inherit sqlalchemy (flask app) in a class, it doesn't recognize functions such as Column()

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I've been building a Flask app with the help of this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dam0GPOAvVI&t=3256s

Here is the file of my **init** so far :

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from os import path

DB_NAME = "database.db"
db = SQLAlchemy()

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'bindthemostselling'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f'sqlite:///{DB_NAME}'
db.init_app(app)
    
from views import views
from auth import auth
    
app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/')
app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix='/')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and here is the file of my models so far its just one class:

```
from flask_login import UserMixin
from . import db

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(150))
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(150))
```

My problem is that the db.Column inside the User class is unrecognizable. I've tried to reinstall sqlalchemy and flask and i've looked at everything he did again and even copied the code from his github and it still wont recognize that function or even other functions that I have noticed so far from the video. This is the first time I try to make an actual python app so maybe there is something i'm missing in the syntax?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**:

So i have updated the **init** file to include everything so i can run and see what error i get here is what I have now:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from os import path
from models import User
from flask_login import LoginManager


DB_NAME = "database.db"
db = SQLAlchemy()

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'bindthemostselling'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f'sqlite:///{DB_NAME}'
db.init_app(app)
    
from views import views
from auth import auth
    
app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/')
app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix='/')

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'
login_manager.init_app(app)

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.get(int(id))

def create_database(app):
    if not path.exists('.' + DB_NAME):
        db.create_all(app=app)
        print('Created Database!')

create_database(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is the traceback that I got (Sorry if the formatting is bad):

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Ashraf\FlaskToDo_*init*_.py", line 4, in 
from models import User
File "c:\Users\Ashraf\FlaskToDo\models.py", line 2, in 
from . import db
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

so apparently the db is not imported correctly? This can't be true cause when I created the User class and passed the db.Model, it recognized it. What am I exactly missing here?

Comment: Can you add Traceback?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the import statement in the models file from

```
from . import db
```

to:

```
from init import db
```

This way you should get a circular import error, so move `from models import User` in your init after db is defined.

This is the complete setup:

init:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from os import path

from flask_login import LoginManager


DB_NAME = "database.db"
db = SQLAlchemy()

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'bindthemostselling'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f'sqlite:///{DB_NAME}'
db.init_app(app)

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'
login_manager.init_app(app)

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.get(int(id))

def create_database(app):
    if not path.exists('.' + DB_NAME):
        db.create_all(app=app)
        print('Created Database!')

create_database(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

from models import User
```

models:

```
from flask_login import UserMixin
from init import db

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(150))
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(150))
```

EDIT:

add a route to actually navigate in your app:

```
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "Hello World"
```

Comment: Ok so it worked but now I get a 404 error whenever I try to go to my local host

Comment: You need to add a route, you may follow the [quickstart example](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application) for clarification.
I also edited my answer!